# Inicialização de matriz com lista vazia "{ }" em C++

Tags: array, c++, matriz, sintaxe, inicialização

Pelo que já vi, é possível inicializar um vetor com a lista vazia, em C++, mas não em C, de modo que todos os elementos do vetor sejam 0:

```
int meuVetor[10] = {}; // Todos os elementos 0, em C++
```

O que aprendi [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/5915941) do SOEn.

É possível, contudo, inicializar uma matriz dessa forma?

```
int minhaMatriz[10][10] = {};
```

Todos os seus elementos seriam 0?

No que testei, só dava falha de segmentação, mas não sei dizer se estava relacionado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível fazer isto sim. Alguns compiladores podem reclamar e exigir uma sintaxe ligeiramente diferente:

```
int minhaMatriz[10][10] = {{0}};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Initialization.c).

Comment: O meu deu certo: https://ideone.com/BLv169. O seu não parece fazer outra coisa.

Comment: É um problema de estouro de memória, diminuindo fica certo.